# Oracle - Audit Trail

Tags: oracle, plsql

Does `oracle` have `Audit Trail` as an inbuilt functionality?

Do i need to create separate table for `Audit Log` purpose to capture `INSERT, UPDATE` and `DELETE` changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Oracle does support auditing.  You won't need to create the audit tables yourself, but you will need to configure the audit settings (i.e. which tables/users/queries to audit).

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/security.htm#i16445